# Conversion of GPS values from deg to dms format

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

Does anyone know how or have an Android function to convert a GPS value from decimal to DMS (degree-minute-second) format?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the class `android.location.Location`.

The static method [`convert(double, Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert%28double,%20int%29) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the math manually.

Example code:

```
decimal = ...;  // Your given value

boolean neg = decimal < 0;
decimal = abs(decimal);

deg = floor(decimal);                  // Round down
minutes = floor((decimal * 60) % 60);  // This is an integer in the range [0, 60)
seconds = (decimal * 3600) % 60;       // This is a decimal in the range [0, 60)

if (neg) prepend minus sign;
```

Comment: Nearly right.  The only problem is that it will give you the wrong answer for latitudes in the Southern hemisphere and longitudes in the Western hemisphere (`floor (-74.0125)` is -75 but the longitude would be 74° 0′ 45″ W).

Comment: See `// Your given value, assumed to be nonnegative`.

Comment: But GPS coordinates cannot be assumed to be non negative.

Comment: +1 although I would usually use the neg flag to append N/S/E/W

Comment: I know you're capable of making that modification on your own.